# Jenkins Blue Ocean use Credentials in Parameterized Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-delivery, jenkins-blueocean

I have a Pipeline Project in the classic Jenkins where I use a parameterized Build that has a secret file (.env file with credentials). This works fine but when I use Blue Ocean, I don't have the same options for a parameterized build. This is the current `Jenkinsfile` I use, which works in the classic Pipeline with a secret file (BOT_SECRET):

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage("prepare .env") {
      environment {
        BOT_SECRET = credentials("${BOT_SECRET}")
      }
      steps {
        sh "> .env"
        sh "echo `cat $BOT_SECRET` > .env"
      }
    }
    stage("build") {
      steps {
        sh "docker build -t telegram-bot ."
      }
    }

    stage("deploy") {
      steps {
        sh "docker-compose up -d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I only found a video about parameterizing the build, but the default options will then be visible to anyone and stored inside the `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: Blue Ocean is just a different GUI, and there does not seem to be a `parameters` block in your `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I didn't need any parameters block in my `Jenkinsfile` when I used the Pipeline. I made the "use parameterized build" setting in the UI and it did not got reflected in the Jenkinsfile I think. Can you clear that up for me?

Comment: This documentation will help: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks, this is almost exactly what I need - I need to have the default password not readable in the Jenkinsfile though. Because this file will be part of an open source project. Or how else can I configure the build through git push to use a different value than the defaultvalue?

Comment: You would want to look into secrets management and webhooks.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks a lot :) Any way of upvoting your comments or giving you credit?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to clear things up so I am answering my own question for anyone who has the same "problem". Credits go to @Matt Schuchard for pointing me in the right direction:

I already knew that secrets exist, but I did use them in a wrong way in my Jenkinsfile. Instead of using an environment variable with paramterized build, I used the Secret by it's ID directly:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('prepare .env') {
      steps {
        sh "> .env"
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'dice_master_env', variable: 'SECRET')]) {
          sh "echo ${SECRET} > .env"
        }
      }
    }

    stage('build') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker build -t telegram-bot .'
      }
    }

    stage('deploy') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker-compose up -d'
      }
    }

  }
}
```

This works now and the credentials are never shared in the git repository. Ultimately it was [this short tutorial](https://fedidat.com/270-jenkinsfile-scripted-secret-text/) that fixed my problem.